# Angular Js syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got the following factory:

```
(function() {
angular.module('temp')
    .factory('Factory',Factory);

    employeeFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
    function employeeFactory($http) {
        var factory = {};
        var vm = this;

        factory.login = function(email,password) {
            return $http({
                'method': 'POST',
                'url': 'http://domain.dev/api/v1/login',
                'data': $.param({
                    'email': email,
                    'password': password
                }),
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });
        return factory;
    }
})();
```

I receive the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

The console refers to the last line:

```
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

Run your code through a code formatter to fix the whitespace. The problem becomes obvious.

```
(function() {
        angular.module('skindustries')
            .factory('employeeFactory', employeeFactory);

        employeeFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

        function employeeFactory($http) {
            var factory = {};
            var vm = this;

            factory.login = function(email, password) {
                return $http({
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'url': 'http://domain.dev/api/v1/login',
                    'data': $.param({
                        'email': email,
                        'password': password
                    }),
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                });
                return factory;
            }
        })();
```

Your last `}`, which you are attempting to use to close the function expression that started on line 1 is actually closing the `employeeFactory` function.

You then need another `}` to close the function expression that started on line 1 before you can have a `)` to match the `(` that is the very first character of the script.

You probably want to put it before the `return factory;` statement as it looks like the missing `}` is the one belonging to the anonymous function you assign to `factory.login`.

Comment: what is the meaning of two return statement inside the `factory.login`?

Comment: Thankyou that helped !

Comment: @JenishRabadiya - The first `return` essentially returns the resulting response from the `POST` request. whereas the second `return`; returns|exposes the factory and its associated api's publicly. So in above example, you're exposing the `login(u,p)` function to other components within your app when this service is injected as dependency in your controller|service etc.

Comment: @Simple-Solution No. That's not correct I believe line `return factory;` would never be executed. Look at the code carefully. return statement has followed by another return statement. I would mark that statement as unreachable code.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `}`

Try this:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('skindustries').factory('employeeFactory', employeeFactory);
    employeeFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
    function employeeFactory($http) {
        var factory = {};
        var vm = this;
        factory.login = function(email, password) {
            return $http({
                'method': 'POST',
                'url': 'http://domain.dev/api/v1/login',
                'data': $.param({
                'email': email,
                'password': password
                }),
                'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });
        }   
        return factory;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were having missing } just before return factory

```
(function() {
  angular.module('skindustries')
    .factory('employeeFactory', employeeFactory);

  employeeFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

  function employeeFactory($http) {
    var factory = {};
    var vm = this;

    factory.login = function(email, password) {
      return $http({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'http://domain.dev/api/v1/login',
        'data': $.param({
          'email': email,
          'password': password
        }),
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      });
    }
    return factory;
  }
})();
```

Comment: That will error. JS Hint reports: Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

Comment: @Quentin Yup I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace self invoking function with this to make it more readable.

```
 (function() {
    angular.module('skindustries').factory('employeeFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

      function login(email, password) {
        return $http({
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'http://domain.dev/api/v1/login',
            'data': $.param({
            'email': email,
            'password': password
          }),
         'headers': {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }
       });
     }


    // expose public api
    return {
      login: login
    };
  }])});
```

Here is a very good guide on [Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) by [John Papa](http://johnpapa.net/)